# What test(s) can I use to compare 4 percentages for both pre- and post-treatment conditions?

Tags: frequency

Have 4 groups of results from 4 different treatments.  Want to compare pre- and post treatment within groups and between groups

Comment: What is the response? Is it a measurement? A count? A binary variable? Ordered categories?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear. Are these 4 groups  similar to each other before treatment ?
If yes then you test the effect of 4 different treatment, if the results of your test is continuous and normally distributed then a simple ANOVA will do fine.